# Replace CSS property with jQuery conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change the background image of a link used to switch the language on my website. My approach was to check which language code is inside the  tags, and then change the background image using jQuery.

The code below changes the background image to the first background-image in the conditional statement. But when the conditional is not met, and the second statement should be executed, it still executes the first (or fails to execute somehow). The console shows no errors.

The last li-element is generated by a PHP script, which could be tweaked to include a -data attribute as suggested in the comments. Which would be an excellent improvement. At the current time it just returns the language code as plain text in a list item.

HTML

```
<nav id="top-menu">
  <ul id="menu-top" class="nav et_disable_top_tier sf-js-enabled">
    <li id="menu-item-263"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-265"><a href="services">Services</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-412"><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="/en/" style="background-image: url(https://www.example.nl/wp-content/themes/GH/images/flagUK.gif);">EN</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
ul#menu-top > li:last-child > a {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: block;
    height: 12px;
    width: 18px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

The jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    lang_flags_append();

    function lang_flags_append() {
        var $l = $( "ul#menu-top > li:last-child > a" ).text();
        console.log($l);
        $( "ul#menu-top li:last-child > a" ).css("background", "");
        if ( $l = 'EN' ) {
            $( "ul#menu-top > li:last-child > a" ).css("background-image", "url('https://www.example.nl/wp-content/themes/GH/images/flagUK.gif')");
        } else if ($l = 'NL') {
            $( "ul#menu-top > li:last-child > a" ).css("background-image", "url('https://www.example.nl/wp-content/themes/GH/images/flagNL.gif')");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `if ( $l === 'NL' )`: you are assigning, not comparing. that's why the first branch is always executed

Comment: An anchor element cannot contains another anchor element, something is wrong in your selector or HTML markup. For the rest, as i can see, see @TrueBlueAussie's asnwser

Comment: Added update to cover what I think you wanted. Please provide the HTML for examples like this to avoid confusion. Your current code was hard-wired to only process the first link (by the look of it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anchors elements do not have a `val()` to return.

Use `text()` or a `data-` attribute

Also (as @Fabrizio Calderan mentioned) you are using a assign `=` and not compare `==` or `===`

e.g.

```
if ( $l == 'NL' )
```

Also as @A. Wolff points out, your selector is broken too (it looks for an anchor within the anchor):

e.g this is enough to find the anchor:

```
$( "ul#menu-top li:last-child > a" )
```

Your best bet is to use data- attributes that contain the country code. Then you can use them to select the image.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var lang = $( "ul#menu-top li:last-child > a" ).data('lang');

    $( "ul#menu-top > li:last-child > a" ).css("background-image", "url('https://www.example.nl/wp-content/themes/GH/images/flag" + lang + ".gif')");
});
```

and your anchor would have

```
<a href="blahblah" data-lang="NL">My anchor</a>
```

### Update:

After re-reading, I see you apparently want to do this to *all* your flag links.

In that case use `each()` to iterate them:

e.g.

```
$(function(){
    $( "ul#menu-top li > a" ).each(function(){
        var lang = $(this).data('lang');
        $(this).css("background-image", "url('https://www.example.nl/wp-content/themes/GH/images/flag" + lang + ".gif')");
   });
});
```

Note: `$(function(){` is just a handy shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: Please *explain* downvotes. Don't just just hit & run! :)

Comment: `$( "ul#menu-top li:last-child > a" ).find("a")` looks wrong too ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff: Thanks. Added that too as well as alternate suggestion. So many errors... so little time :)

Comment: I have used the text() function and it returns the correct value. I also removed the .find("a") because I was already selecting the <a>tag. However, the conditional statement still returns the first value in all cases. I have updated my code above.

Comment: Please a) follow my suggestion to replace the code with data attributes and b) provide your HTML as we can't see why you select the `last-child` link only :)

Comment: The problem was as @Fabrizio Calderan suggested that I was assigning and not comparing. A silly mistake :( Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I still suggest a) improving your code to be data-driven and b) providing the HTML so that answers can be completed :)